# Insert header guards in .h and .hpp files via nerdtree and vim

Tags: c++, vim, nerdtree

lets say i want to add header guards for .h and .hpp files. name of the header guards must depend on the name of the file. How does one make that on every creation of .h and .hpp file via nerdtree, those header guards are inserted?

Comment: `name of the header guards must depend on the name of the file` What if you have dir1/header.h and dir2/header.h?

Comment: only header will be used

Answer (score 0):

This can get you started:

```
function Cpp_print_header()                                          
  let header_guard_name = toupper(expand('%:t:gs/[^0-9a-zA-Z_]/_/g'))
  let str_header_guard = ["#ifndef " . header_guard_name,            
    \"#define " . header_guard_name,                                 
    \"",                                                             
    \"#endif /* " . header_guard_name . " */"]                       
  call setline(line("$"), str_header_guard)                          
                                                                     
endfunction                                                          
                                                                     
command CppPrintHeader :call Cpp_print_header()                      
autocmd BufNewFile *.h,*.hpp :CppPrintHeader
```

Comment: It's better to put autocmd in a group (and to avoid polluting the global namespace with functions; ` s:`  functions are perfect here)

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach is to use a template-expander plugin. That's what I do with [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/) -- which even support naming policies for inclusion guards that can be overridden differently in different projects.

It can also be done manually by listening `BufNewFile` event and then expanding inclusion guards manually (see perreal's answer for instance).

PS: NerdTree is unrelated to the problem nor the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward solution with `autocmd`

```
function! InsertHeaderGuard()
    " Modify the define name format to your liking
    let def = 'header_' . localtime() . '_' . expand('%:t:r') . '_' . expand('%:e')
    
    " Append to the buffer 
    call append(0, '#ifndef ' . def)
    call append(1, '#define ' . def)
    call append(2, '')
    call append(3, '')
    call append(4, '')
    call append(5, '#endif')
    
    " Place cursor at line 4 column 1
    call cursor(4, 1)
endfunction

" C++ headers
autocmd BufNewFile *.hpp call InsertHeaderGuard()
```

It insert include guard and put cursor inside the guard so you can start typing instead moving the cursor to the position

[image: Output]

Note:

1. Ignore syntax highlight error in my answer